# Google Drive API: Uploading and creating folders with http requests, for example in DIO with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, google-drive-api, dio

I'm trying to create a simple Flutter app which interacts with the Google Drive API.
Authentication works great via the Google Sign In package, so I have access to the correct headers and auth tokens.

What I don't understand however, despite trying different approaches and reading the Drive Documentation up and down - how can I interact with the API via http requests, for example via Dio or via the "standard" way in dart/flutter?

To state one example: I want to upload an an image the user picked. I have everything figured out (the file path, the auth token, etc.), but how does a http request look like?

Here is the "bare" http request:

```
Map headers = await user.currentUser.authHeaders;

var formData = FormData.fromMap({
    'name': filePath,
    'file': MultipartFile.fromBytes(fileData, filename: filePath)
  });

var response = await Dio().post(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media',
       data: formData,
      options: Options(headers: headers));

  print(response);
```

It's probably a very mundane/trivial question, but I just can't figure it out ..

Thanks in advance for your help!
Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the File first then upload the file data into it.

I'll using the http plugin and not DIO. But the same process should work for dio.

**Step one: Create the file metadata in a folder**

```dart
Future<String> createFile({File image, String folderId}) async {
  String accessToken = await Prefs.getToken();
  Map body = {
    'name': 'name.jpg',
    'description': 'Newly created file',
    'mimeType': 'application/octet-stream',
    'parents': ['$folderId']
  };
  var res = await http.post(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: jsonEncode(body),
  );
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    // Extract the ID of the file we just created so we 
    // can upload file data into it
    String fileId = jsonDecode(res.body)['id'];
    // Upload the content into the empty file
    await uploadImageToFile(image, fileId);
    // Get file (downloadable) link and use it for anything
    String link = await getFileLink(fileId);
    return link;
  } else {
    Map json = jsonDecode(res.body);
    throw ('${json['error']['message']}');
  }
}
```

**Step two: Upload image data into empty file**

```dart
Future uploadImageToFile(File image, String id) async {
  String accessToken = await Prefs.getToken();
  String mimeType = mime(basename(image.path).toLowerCase());
  print(mimeType);
  var res = await http.patch(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/$id?uploadType=media',
    body: image.readAsBytesSync(),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
      'Content-Type': '$mimeType'
    },
  );
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    return res.body;
  } else {
    Map json = jsonDecode(res.body);
    throw ('${json['error']['message']}');
  }
}
```

**Step three: Get downloadable file link(to store in database or use for anything)**

```dart
Future getFileLink(String id) async {
  String accessToken = await Prefs.getToken();
  var res = await http.get(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$id?fields=webContentLink',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    },
  );
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    Map json = jsonDecode(res.body);
    String link = json['webContentLink'];
    return link.split('&')[0];
  } else {
    Map json = jsonDecode(res.body);
    throw ('${json['error']['message']}');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! These three steps really help me understand the syntax of http requests in combination with the Google Drive API. I was not able to "translate" the Drive API documentation to actual requests, so I can now learn from your steps and examples. Thank you again!